# IIS stop responding for a single page sometimes not alway

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application that works fine in all of its pages but I have a page that the IIS stop responding when I request it --> load forever in FF and from my iPad safari said that the web server stop responding.

When I reset IIS it works fine for a while and then i face the same problem again.

I do nothing critical nor complicated in this page load it is all about http request and it works fine in local host very fine also!!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the server event log, usually when something is going wrong you'll see it in there.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution here

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx?mfr=true

when i make that the pool will recycle after 1 or 2 requests this solve the problem at all !

thanks

Comment: you should sign up for an account, then you will use the same account each time rather than creating a new one each time you post.